# Python 3: write method vs. os.write number of bytes returned

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, utf-8

I wanted to create a text file containing a number of ''pages'' and log the byte offset of each page in a separate file. To do that, I printed strings to the main output file and counted bytes using `bytes_written += file.write(str)`. However, the byte offset was often wrong.

I switched to `bytes_written += os.write(fd, bytes(str, 'UTF-8'))` and it works now. What is the difference between `write()` and `os.write()`? Or is the difference in the return value simply due to my manual conversion of the string to UTF-8?

Comment: If you're on Windows, and the file is being written in text mode, then two bytes (cr+lf) will be written for every line ending where the original string only has one. If `file.write()` doesn't count the bytes properly in this case, I would consider that a bug, but in any case the problem could be rectified by making sure the file is opened in `"wb"` mode.

Comment: An other similar point about *text* files: the value returned by `tell` is **not** the byte index in the file, nor the character index. It's just a number that `seek` can use to return to that position, but you aren't supposed to do much about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the difference between `write()` and `os.write()`?

It's analogous to the difference between the C functions [`fwrite(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) and [`write(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

The latter is a thin wrapper around an OS-level [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), whereas the former is part of the standard C library, which does some additional buffering, and ultimately calls the latter when it actually needs to write its buffered data to a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

Python 3.x adds some additional logic to a `file` object's `write()` method which does automatic character-encoding conversion for Python `str` objects, whereas Python 2.x does not.

> Or is the difference in the return value simply due to my manual conversion of the string to UTF-8?

In Python 3.x, the difference is more related to the way in which you opened the file.

If you opened the file in binary mode, e.g. `f = open(filename, 'wb')` then `f.write()` expects a `bytes` object, and will return the number of **bytes** written.

If, instead, you opened the file in text mode, e.g. `f = open(filename, 'w')` then `f.write()` expects a `str` object, and will return the number of **characters** written, which for multi-byte encodings such as UTF-8 may not match the number of bytes written.

Note that the `os.write()` method always expects a `bytes` object, regardless of whether or not the `O_BINARY` flag was used when calling `os.open()`.